# using LINQ to get a particular set of objects from a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a code that returns a set of objects. I want to segregate a particular object from that set. I'm trying to use LINQ to do that. But I'm not getting that,

```
var registerAck = ((pointAck)((response.Item))).Items[0].Item;

var poke = ((pointAck)((response.Item))).Items.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(poker));
```

I'm getting a System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator<> in my poke.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Adding `.ToList` may or may not be required, because it depends on how you want to use `poke`.
   For example, if you are going to iterate over the results using `foreach` only once, then `.ToList` is redundant, and unnecessary code execution and allocations.

In short, there **may be nothing wrong** with your code, depending on how you want to further use `poke`.

2. While we are at it, FYI, there is an alternative to specific filtering you are doing here with `Where` method.. Checkout `.OfType`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx

It will be slightly more compact and more readable.
`Items.OfType<poker>();`

Answer (score 3):

Add `.ToList()` to convert it to the type of `System.Collections.Generic.List<TSource>`

```
var poke = ((pointAck)((response.Item))).Items
           .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(poker)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found out too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I forgot to add .ToList(). It works.

```
var poke = ((pointAck)((response.Item))).Items.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(poker)).ToList();
```